# How to data-bind WTK component in child bxml file

Tags: java, desktop-application, apache-pivot

I am using Apache Pivot 2.0.2 and I am trying to build a DesktopApplication.

My problem is that I have a ListView or really - whatever object in my application, defined in bxml file. I can give it an ID or anything - no problem.

But now, how should I obtain this object in Java and affect changes I make to it?

Since my bxml are including other bxml files; after

> this.window.open(display);

I have tried to obtain a certain object with:

> bxmlSerializer.getNamespace().get("musicPanel");

And i can have the object with everything I put in BXML. I can even change its properties BUT
**its not being reflected on the GUI!** Nothing changes!

So I thought I could find my object in the

> window.getContent();

but I cannot find a method to get an object with ID.

Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its hard to explain, but mainly I had to restructure my application and use my own namespace as in the example:

[Stock Tracker Example](http://pivot.apache.org/tutorials/stock-tracker.html)

And it was useful to get the full sourcecode of these examples:

[Sourcecode](http://pivot.apache.org/download.cgi)